# Remove post method and initialize for each loop in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to remove **input->post** at the line **$attain = $this->input->post('mytext', true);** .Itried this with many ways but errors display. How can I get rid of this post method?

```
$attain = $this->input->post('mytext', true);
        $data2=array(); //<-initialize
            foreach ($attain as $i => $a) { // need index to match other properties
                //append array
                $data2[] = array(
                'mytext' => $a,
                'projectname'=> $this->input->post('projectname'),
            );
            //for multiple entry in same table
            $this->db->insert_batch('projectem', $data2); 

        //}
    }
```

This is my view where user produce dynamic inputs

```
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('</br><div><input class="input form-control"" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
    </script> 
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_field_button">Add More Fields</button> 
                    </div>

                </div>
```

This is how 3values save in the database 
[image]

Comment: What errors did you get?  Maybe pick the most common one, and the code that produces it, and add those here.

Comment: Mr.Joshua I used this code to save dynamic inputs get from user.But this loop repeat some values at the database. Actually I want to stop that

Comment: Please edit your question to say so, preferably including samples of the input(s) and the desired output(s) verses the actual output(s).

Comment: I edit my question Mr.Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments above i think your trouble is that the same data is inserting multiple times. If this is the case,

I think u missed a closing bracket .Try `$this->db->insert_batch('projectem', $data2);` outside the loop

```
$attain = $this->input->post('mytext', true);
$data2 = array(); //<-initialize

foreach($attain as $i => $a)
{  
    $data2[] = array(
      'mytext' => $a,
      'projectname' => $this->input->post('projectname') ,
    );

}  // modification here

 /*
  * if the insert_batch is inside the loop, insert will
  * occur multiple times with
  */ 

  $this->db->insert_batch('projectem', $data2);
```

Comment: Thank you JayaKrishanan..it's so simple...I wonder why I missed it. Thanks